# How to change Apache httpd.conf file on Mac OS X?

Tags: shell, vim, cgi, apache

I'm on a MacBook running OS X trying to teach myself how to write CGI scripts and I'm stuck on the very first step, altering the `httpd.conf` file. I'm following these instructions: http://www.cgi101.com/book/connect/mac.html and I'm trying to alter the `httpd.conf` file using the terminal command `sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. However when I get ready to try and save the file it says that it's read-only. The instructions that I'm following say that I'm supposed to uncomment the line `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` however, how am I supposed to do this if I can't save the file?

I'm very new to CGI scripts, Apache and terminal in general.

EDIT: The output from the command: `ls -l /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is:

```
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  24330 Jul 11  2011 /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

EDIT: When I try to save it says `add ! to override`. When I do so using the command `:!x` it exits out but produces the error `launch_msg("CheckIn") IPC failure: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: can you paste the output of 'ls -l /etc/apache2/httpd.conf' thanks

Comment: try to execute 'sudo su', enter root pass, than edit and save file... If you're using Vim, save your file with :wq! or fast key - Shift+ZZ

Comment: Nope, even after executing `sudo su` it still is readonly.

Comment: well - make it writable - as root: 'chmod u+w /etc/apache2/httpd.conf' BTW don't you have apache2.conf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save read-only file add `!` after Vim command, not before. If you add it after, then it will try to run shell command (not Vim command). In this case you are running shell command named `x`, that prints message that you mentioned. You need `:x!` to save and close or `:w!` to just save file.

Comment: I have been using the sudo command, but I still get the same readonly waring. See edit in my original post.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, didn't see it. Can you try to save it with ":w!" command then?

Comment: P. S. About you last update: Add "!" after vim command, not before. If you add it after, then it will try to run Terminal command (not vim command). In this case you are runing Terminal command named "x", that prints message that you mentioned. You need ":x!" to save and close or ":w!" to just save file.