# How do U edit a httpd.conf file in a Mac?

Tags: apache

I open up my httpd.conf file in TextWrangler and make some changes. When I restart my servers, I can see the new code vanish.

I've Google'd for help, and this is apparently a common problem. One solution that worked for some people is to copy the httpd.conf file to another file, modify it, then drag it back into its original folder. But that doesn't work for me.

Some suggested changing the permissions under Get Info. However, it says I already have Read & Write privileges. I then changed it so that EVERYBODY has Read & Write privileges.

I've also found suggestions for some sort of "sudo" operation with Terminal, but it sounds complex - and a little dangerous. I don't want to mess things up.

I found a similar discussion @ [How to change Apache httpd.conf file on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333267/how-to-change-apache-httpd-conf-file-on-mac-os-x) but it sounds pretty technical. Is there a user friendly way to modify a httpd.conf file on a Mac?

I'm using Max OS X Lion, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried making your changes and then restarting `httpd` from the command line rather than enabling/disabling with System Preferences? I have changed httpd.conf many times on Mac OS X, but I always do it with the commmand line approach with emacs/vim, etc., and even using those editors goes far beyond what I can explain quickly. But try making your changes with TextWrangler and then typing this into Terminal `sudo apachectl -k restart` (And by the way, be sure to change the permissions of the file back to something that doesn't give anyone else write privileges.)

Comment: I pasted your code into Terminal and hit return, and it gave me an error: /usr/sbin/apachectl: line 90: 16959 Bus error: 10           $HTTPD $ARGV I wonder if I need a special password to edit httpd.conf? I just typed in the password I use for everything on my Mac. Maybe I should dowdnload emacs or Vim. I can't believe how unbelievably complex Apache is; it makes PHP look like a kindergarten game. ;)

Comment: Note: I just downloaded MacVim and edited my file with it, with the same results - restarting Apache zaps the changes.